# Convert string to keycode in vimscript

Tags: vim

Is there some way that I can convert the string `<C-a>` into the key code that's presented by `\<C-a>` dynamically in Vimscript? I want to make `<C-a>` an option the user can specify for a binding, but detect `\<C-a>` at runtime by examining the result of getchar(). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand, what’s the problem with `getchar()`? If you need string out of it you usually write something like

```
let char=getchar()
if type(char)==type(0)
    let char=nr2char(char)
endif
```

and compare it as usual:

```
if char is# "\<C-a>"
    …
endif
```

. If you need the right side of comparison be some user-defined variable it is not a problem, just tell users to use `let g:var="\<C-a>"` in place of `let g:var="<C-a>"`. Though using latter is also possible: the following trick will transform `"<C-a>"` into `"\<C-a>"`:

```
let string=eval('"'.escape(string, '\"<').'"')
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to do exactly `let g:var="<C-a>"` instead of `let g:var="\<C-a>"` since I want to use the variable in a map command as well as comparing it with the result of getchar() like you described above. Your last command works perfectly! Didn't know about eval() before. I ended up using `exec 'let string = "\'.'<C-a>'.'"'` which also seems to work, but I like your way much better!

Comment: @terryma `noremap ^A` (where `^A` is raw control character) works just as good as `noremap <C-a>`. You don’t need to use `<>` notation in `*map` commands. In fact, they even will not work if some vi compatibility settings are turned on (never seen them turned on on other people setups though).

Comment: @terryma The only case where you will be forced to use `<>` notation is space in `lhs`.

Comment: This didn't work for some users of my plugin when they tried to map command key in Mac. For example `"\<D-D>"` was causing issues for some users and `<D-D>` worked. The only way I found to resolve their issue was to let them map `<D-D>` but convert it to `"\<D-D>"` inside the plugin where I need to compare it with the result of `getchar()`